# Arrays with trailing commas inside an array initializer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Array initializers can be used to initialize arrays at compile-time. An initializer with  trailing commas as shown below compiles fine.

```
int a[][] = {{1,2,} ,{3,4,} , {5,6,},}; //Trailing commas cause no compiler error

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output :

```
1        2        
3        4        
5        6
```

---

Also legal with one dimension arrays as obvious with the above discussion.

```
int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,}; //A trailing comma causes no compiler error

for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print(b[i]+"\t");
}
```

Output :

```
1        2        3        4        5        6
```

---

Even the following is a legal syntax and compiles fine.

```
int c[][] = {{,} ,{,} , {,},};
```

The compiler should expect a constant value (or another initializer) after and before a comma `,`. How is this compiled? Does the compiler simply ignore such commas or something else happens in such a scenario?

Comment: A trailing comma is ignored. It's allowed by the language since some find it convenient.

Comment: @Daniel Well it keeps diffs more succinct when adding things to arrays, allows easy reordering of array expressions and enables a simpler grammar for the language all in one go. Quite some advantages for no downsides I can see.

Comment: @Voo How does it make the grammar simpler? If the trailing comma were mandatory, that would make it simpler, but with an optional trailing comma, I don't see it. Nor can I see the greater succinctness of diffs. Reordering, yes.

Comment: @Daniel Right you are about the grammar, I forgot that they're still optional. About diffs: Assume that for larger arrays every item gets its own line (I see that relatively often and while it's not always sensible, there are lots of situations where it's useful - also leaves place for comments without resorting to /* */ inlining). Adding a new line then only changes a single line in the diff, without it you'd have to change two.

Comment: @Voo I see. But if you lay out your arrays Haskell style, with leading commas, it wouldn't change two lines - except if you add an entry at the first position, but that's much rarer than adding at the end.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah that works, although that style would look strange to me, especially since style guides for other languages (never written a single line haskel and lisp avoids the whole problem in the first place) generally favor having operators at the end of a line (i.e. `x && \\y` instead of `x \\ && y`; or english where you leave punctuation at the end of the line as well); but it helps with reordering and adding things at the end. As always several solutions to a problem with different tradeoffs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14314/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-voo)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The trailing comma is ignored. From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

Comment: as a side note: the above statement is present even in JLS 1.0 http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/ (reaching back to Java 1.0), so we can safely say "it was always there".