# Weird declaration in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arrays with trailing commas inside an array initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621917/arrays-with-trailing-commas-inside-an-array-initializer-in-java)

Why the following statement is correct in java:

```
int[][] a = { {1,2,}, {3,4}};
```

Whether should be compilation error because of unnecessary comma ?

Comment: What is the compilation error you see?This is valid java.

Comment: I believe the question is about the trailing comma in the first sub-array.

Comment: int[][] a = { { 1, 2, }, { 3, 4, }, };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Trailing comma` in a array initialization like that are `ignored by compiler`. Those are generally added so that later on adding something to the array, just requires adding the element without worrying about comma.

It is wierd, but is allowed.

This is also listed in [`JLS - Section#10.6 (Array Initializers)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6): -

> An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of
>   expressions, enclosed by braces { and }.
>
> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array
>   initializer and is ignored.

Comment: +1 I was just looking up the reference in the JLS but you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
{1,2,}
```

There does not have to be an element following the last comma. This is the case for several programming languages (JavaScript (*[by standards](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5); IE doesn't always conform*), PHP, Java, Python, C# 3.5, and others, I'm sure).

Comment: Yes and `c` - where they all inherit their syntax from.

Comment: @Eric: JavaScript does *not* allow a trailing comma; although many browsers accept it, IE does not.

Comment: @GregHewgill C *does* allow the trailing comma, actually: http://codepad.org/X7RyANgi. Good note about IE, though, I'll add it.

Comment: @GregHewgill I disagree, it's in the ANSI standard. http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt  `initializer:
                  assignment-expression
                  {  initializer-list } 
                  {  initializer-list , }
`

Comment: @GregHewgill better link: http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/c_html/c.html#s6.5.7

Comment: @weston: I stand corrected, all this time I've believed it was a (widespread) compiler extension. Thanks.

Comment: @GregHewgill Maybe you were thinking of enums declarations, which trailing commas are not standard.

Answer (score 2):

This question is most likely about the trailing comma in the first array element of the 2-dimensional array: `{1,2,}`. This is valid java syntax according to the [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a multidimensional array. For a standard array, you'd have

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

But this is multidimensional. Maybe this will help:

```
int a[][] = {
                {1, 2},
                {3, 4}
            }
```

so now `a[0] = {1, 2}` and `a[1] = {3, 4}`

If you're referring to the final comma in `{1, 2,}`, that's fine in Java.

Comment: He is asking about the trailing comma in `(1,2,)` and nt the row seperator

Answer (score 0):

Its a nested array - why would there be a compilation error?

Comment: I know, but it's strange that there is no error in compilation IMHO

Comment: @przemek You can terminate the last element of the array with a comma. It is not a syntax error. For example this is also a valid declaration `int[][] a = { {1,2,}, {3,4,},};`